# arecord has terrible quality

Tags: command-line, audio-recording

Im having trouble with the sound recorder app, so I tried `arecord a.wav`
the recording sound is terrible.... I read the man page but did not see any provisions to change the sound recording parameters. How can I record s sound in ubuntu mate 18.04, or improve the quality of arecord?

[check it out.](http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/a.wav)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audacity audio editor has configurable output sound quality in *Edit* -> *Preferences*. Audacity can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo apt install audacity
```

[image: Audacity preferences]

Audacity is designed for easy recording, playing and editing of digital audio. Supported file formats include Ogg Vorbis, MP2, MP3, FLAC, WAV, AIFF, and AU.

Answer (score 8):

You can significantly change the audio quality using `-f`/`--format` (format name) for example (see [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/arecord.1.html)):

```
arecord -vv --format=cd file.wav
```

Will record a snippet in "CD" quality (finish with <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> when done).

`-f` cd is format shortcut for (16 bit little endian, 44100, stereo) where default format is (Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono).

Some other examples:

```sh
arecord -vv -f=cd --duration=10 file.wav                # Same but with a fixed duration of 10 seconds
arecord -vv -f=cd --file-type raw | lame -r - file.mp3  # Record and save it as mp3
arecord --list-devices                                  # List all sound cards and digital audio devices
```